# Выборка COLUMN по GROUP BY по индивидуальным условиям для каждого COLUMN в одном запросе

Tags: sql, select, group-by

Допустим есть база MySQL хранилища, наподобие GIT.
Колонки: файл, хеш данных файла, дата последнего изменения (хеширования).
При изменении файла появляется новая строка с этим же именем файла, новым хешем и новой датой обновления. Как сделать выборку всех файлов и их хешей (две колонки) на дату 'xxxx'? Т.е. чтобы выводился файл и последний хеш на дату, которая не больше указанной в условии даты 'xxxx'?

есть:

```
file | hash | date
-----+------+-----
 one | d17f | 2017
-----+------+-----
 two | a001 | 2018
-----+------+-----
 one | caf3 | 2019
-----+------+-----
 two | abcd | 2015
```

Нужно (до 2019, включительно):

```
file | hash
-----+-----
 two | a001
 one | caf3
```

Пробую

```
select file, max(f_date) as date from b_data where f_date <=date('2019-01-01') group by file;

file | date
 two | 2018
 one | 2019
```

Уже находит дату последнего изменения файла, предшествующую или равную нужной, но если в `select` добавить в выборку hash, то вылетает `error 1055 (42000) SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column`

`select file, group_concat(hash), max(f_date) as date from b_data where f_date <=date('2019-01-01') group by file;`

```
file | hash       | date
 two | a001, abcd | 2018
 one | d17f, caf3 | 2019
```

дает все хеши просто кучей, разумеется, не сортированные по дате.

Как сделать так, чтобы были строчки файл, хеш, дата последнего изменения до даты 'x' всех файлов в одном запросе?

Answer (score 1):

Сделал без использования GROUP BY, через доп выборку наложением таблицы на таблицу с помощью WHERE:

```
select file, hash
from temp_table t1
where file_date = (
    select max(file_date)
    from temp_table t2
    where t1.file = t2.file and date(file_date)<='2018-11-25'
    )
;
```

Comment: Если сделать связь через Inner join, работать будет быстрее и легче, если это Вам нужно.